# HTML5 black videos

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a website with a very simple HTML5 video.  I have one source for the video, and it preloads and auto-plays.  There is no javascript involved.  Yet somehow something is very wrong.  After playing the video once or twice, every video I have turns black if one is viewed again!  The audio is fine, but the entire video is completely black.  Sometimes the picture will load after a half a minute or so, but the videos I have are 10-30 seconds long, so it doesn't matter by then.  The "video" will already have played through.  I don't know how something this simple could get so messed up.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<video style="border: 2px solid green;" controls="controls" height="500" 
       preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay"><source src="vid/somevideo.mp4" 
       type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 videos.</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.  It seems that the video did not want to have that green border put around it.  I don't know why though...